# How to get data with php and it pass to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to create an audio player for a project am working on, I don't know, its kinda weird but, is it possible I get a url (or any data) from my mysql table and then pass it to a JavaScript variable. Kindly let me know if its possible and how to do it or tell me if there's another way out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$foo = 7;

?>

<script>
    var foo = <?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>;
</script>
```

That's basically it... json_encode() here is technically not required, but it's never a good idea to blindly dump data from PHP into a JS context, so it's more of a seat belt - a good habit to get into.

Comment: A very good habit to get into! It has bit me in the butt multiple times!

Comment: Thanks Marc B....never knew it'd b done like its in HTML! Been of great help bro! I appreciate!

Comment: <?php
$me = 'I am a boy';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var me = "<?php print($me); ?>";
document.write(me);
</script> did it that way and it worked...basically what I need

Comment: yes, but you're dumping text from PHP into JS. try adding a quote into that string, e.g. `$me = "I ain't a girl"` and see how things work out...